# What is the pixel value for 1 REM (Root Ephemeral Units) for IE edge?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, pixel

I did some google search, but could not find out what is the default pixel value (1 rem) for edge. If someone could put a link here, that will be appreciated. e.g. xx pixel === 1 rem, for edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any doc talking about it, but I can give you an answer: `16px === 1rem` in Edge (with font size set to "Medium" in Edge settings).

I did a simple test. I set the font-size in CSS to be `1rem`, and inspected its pixel value in DevTools. It says `16px`. See the pic below:[image]

But if you change the font size inside browser, this equation will break. Simply put,

Very small: `9px === 1rem`

Small: `12px === 1rem`

Medium: `16px === 1rem`

Large: `20px === 1rem`

Very large: `24px === 1rem`